# Auto click on element after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I want to make a link to the following web page http://www.iph-hannover.de/de/iph/mitarbeiter but after it opens an auto click on one of the member's pictures should be generated.

So after clicking the link it should load the page and popup the window of one of the members as if I clicked on his profile with the mouse.
Note that I can not change anything on the http://www.iph-hannover.de/de/iph/mitarbeiter webpage. I can only link to it.

My basic html knowledge is all about making text bold/italic/colorful and creating hyper links with "a href". So please more detailed answers.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't do this.

If you can't change anything on the mitarbeiter page then there's nothing you can do about how the page opens. There's lots of easy ways to send information from one page to another, but that doesn't help anything when you can't make the mitarbeiter page "respond" to the information you want to send.

*(when I say "information" then I really mean 'any' kind of data that the receiving page can act on, like a "open  Prof. Peter Nyhuis on load" kind of message)*

Comment: Thank You! I wasted a lot of time trying to figure this out.